# Joining files with Unix

Tags: unix, join

I am trying to join three files. I get roughly how to do it. I need to join 2, then join that one to the third one. My problem is I am pretty sure I need to use -j and -o but I am not sure how to use them. These are the three files I need to join can someone help me?

```
LN.txt
Jones:John
Kelly:Mary
Adams:Betty
Reich:Richard

PH.txt
Jones:905-555-1212
Kelly:416-555-2424
Adams:416-555-5757
Reich:905-555-8989

AD.txt
Jones:Toronto
Kelly:Calgary
Adams:Calgary
Reich:Toronto
```

Obviously I only need the use of their last names once.

Comment: Which shell?  It matters because Bash has [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) which other shells do not, and that makes it easier to make the the command work correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, you can change the order of the files to suit your needs:

```
join -t':' LN.txt PH.txt | join -t':'  - AD.txt > outputFile.txt
```

As suggested by @Jonathan Leffler, adding the following to work for unsorted files in bash:

```
join -t':' <(sort LN.txt) <(sort PH.txt) | join -t':'  - <(sort AD.txt)
```

Comment: The inputs to `join` must be sorted on the joining field, at least for reliable operation.

Comment: Agree, I will add that. Thanks!

Comment: With the given data, where the joining column is in the same order in each file, the `join` sequence above works (at least on Mac OS X 10.9.2). With Bash, `join -t: <(sort LN.txt) <(sort PH.txt) | join -t: - <(sort AD.txt)` would be reliable — which is what you added to the answer just before I posted this comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, could I have used the -j and -o and this is just a different way or they are all together just not needed?

Comment: @Kalkrin - `-j` is for joining on a specific field and `-o` is formatting the output. They are useful but not required in your particular case. `-t` was required because your input has `:` as field seperator. You can read more on Join and play around with it to understand it better

Answer (score 1):

[Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22752251/970195) has a good solution using `join`. This is a reference that you can achieve the same using `awk` as your choice of tool.

```
$ awk -F: '{
    names[$1] = ((names[$1]) ? names[$1] : "")FS $2
}
END {
    for(n in names) 
        print n names[n]
}' LN.txt PH.txt AD.txt
Jones:John:905-555-1212:Toronto
Kelly:Mary:416-555-2424:Calgary
Adams:Betty:416-555-5757:Calgary
Reich:Richard:905-555-8989:Toronto
```